# Density of states in Frequency Space vs K Space

Tags: solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals

Why do we use the density of states in frequency space when the density of states in k space is one state per unit k cubed (in 3 dimensions0?

Answer (score 2):

In solid state physics we often have to integrate (or sum) over k-states up to a certain energy. So it is useful to have the density of states as a function of energy (or frequency), since then
$$ \int d^3k \ldots = \int dE \,{\cal D}(E)\ldots $$
with ${\cal D}(E)$ being the density of states. (Note that $E=\hbar\omega$.)

Answer (score 2):

k-space is multi-dimensional while frequency/energy space is one-dimensional. Often it is mathematically convenient and intuitively simpler to work with one dimensional integrals over energy than three (or so) dimensional integrals over k-space.

Edit: of course the price we pay, as you point out, is that while density of states is uniform in k-space it is non-uniform in energy space so now we must carry the extra “baggage” of the density of states. This is the trade off. A lot of time/effort is spent understanding/building intuition about the density of states about various systems
so that we can calculate much of what we want in an energy picture.